# android обновление

Tags: android

Мне надо заменить версию 4.1.3 на canara. В старой версии есть проекты которые нужны. Если я переустанавливаю студию могу я это сделать без удаления старой версии. Если нет, то когда я буду удалять через "программы и компоненты" у меня удалятся проекты?

Comment: Проекты не удалятся. Ставить можно не заменяя, а рядом. Можно разные версии студии иметь одновременно.

Comment: чтобы рядом поставить надо просто установить?

Comment: Да, если имена папок не совпадут то оно не перезатрёт другую версию.